# Bundle Deactivation in Spring OSGI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, osgi, osgi-bundle

In spring dynamic module what happens to the dependent bundles when their service provider bundle is deactivated. Will they too get deactivated?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no direct dependency between a service provider and consumer, as the service interfaces should be declared external to the implementors.

When a service is deactivated, the consumer of the Spring injected service (which is a proxy) will simply attempt to access the service and eventually fail if the proxy cannot find a suitable service implementation within the timeout period (I believe it defaults to 5 min).  This would be consistent with the dynamic nature of OSGi in which service references are meant to be able to be added and removed at runtime.  Applications in such a dynamic environment must be aware of this and be coded appropriately to handle the fact that services may not always be available.

Comment: And they should also be VERY aware that these services must be stateless ... Also, in general service provider bundles should add the service package to their exports since they are very tightly coupled to this API, unlike consumers which benefit from backward compatibility. They should always import the service API package.